# In Keycloak, how do I customize my login theme so that social providers are at the top?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I seem to have trouble here with social logins for Keycloak. On the login page, it displays first username-and-password, and then below it puts the buttons for login-through-social. Is it possible to have those social login buttons at the top?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom theme for the login page where you put the identity providers above the user/password form. Refer to the Keycloak documentation on how to create a theme: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes

Keycloak uses so-called [Freemarker templates](https://freemarker.apache.org/) for their themes, which are similar to HTML syntax.

You can simply copy for example the Keycloak login page and look for the corresponding parts. From the top of my head, I think the element for the identity provider is called "kc-socials" or something like that.

Comment: As much as RTFM this is, it answered my question in a way. I started altering those ftl files, and noticed that I didn't get the expected results. My issue was acutally that I was running an older Keycloak, and used newer FTL files I found from their GitHub repo.